# How to force two element alignment in the same line bootstrap model

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<h4 class="modal-title">
   Simple title
   <div id="abs">1419698355</div>
</h4>
```

Using this code i'm getting the simple title on one line and the id on the next line.
How can i force them to be display the same line?

Comment: #abs {display:inline} if not work try to add !important

Comment: use a `<span>` (which is an inline element), `<div>` doesn't belong in an `h4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#abs{display:inline}

 <h4 class="modal-title">
       Simple title
       <div id="abs">1419698355</div>
    </h4>
```

Or you can just use the  attribute

```
<h4 class="modal-title">
   Simple title
   <span id="abs">1419698355</span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

give style to abs as float left

```
#abs{
float:left;
}
<div id="abs" style="float:left;">1419698355</div>
```

Comment: I highly doubt OP expected the number to precede the text

Answer (score -1):

Element `<div>` is not allowed as a child of element `<h2>` in HTML 4.01/XHTML. But, in HTML5 it is allowed.:

```
#abs{display:inline}

<h4 class="modal-title">
     Simple title
     <span id="abs">1419698355</span>
</h4>  `
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking what kind of HTML was allowed. This is more of a comment than an answer